# Ionic file download not working in native app but working in web app (browser)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am just checking on any file download from server. Below code is working on browser but not in APP. Seems that below code not working

```
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
```

My full code:

```
downloadFile(directory: string, filename: string = null): void {

    const baseUrl = this.service.Base_Url + 'download.php?dir=files/' + directory + '/&file=' + filename;

    this.service.process_download(baseUrl).subscribe(

      (response: any) => {

        //Check Blob size | File is available or not

        if (response.size > 0) {

          let dataType = response.type;
          let binaryData = [];
          binaryData.push(response);
          let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');

          downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, { type: dataType }));

          if (filename) {
            downloadLink.setAttribute('download', filename);
          }

          document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
          downloadLink.click();
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

process function:-

```
public process_download(url: any) {    
    if (this.Base_Url != undefined) {
      return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' });
    }
  }
```

download.php is a download script.

```
//Download function starts from here
    $varFilePath = SOURCE_ROOT . $varDir . $varFile;
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $varFile);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($varFilePath));
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    @readfile($varFilePath);
    exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is browse related code like pure javascript website so this is working in the browser,

you need to use this "**file-transfer**" plugin to achieve in the native device.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer

thanks.

Comment: thanks for reply. I want to do this without file plugin.